# VBA to copy information down but on a loop

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I tried to run this in a macro but somehow the loop didn’t work as it kept referencing the cells when I need this to just run down until it hits the end. I am looking to do the following:

If there is a value in column D and nothing in column B then the information need to be copied down. To copy it will look for column A to match but look for the top line of the match so there is values in column B. once it finds the top row the code should copy down rows B,E & H

the code i used is a recorded macro. this look for a value in B goes to the bottom (using Ctrl + Down) copies this value and uses Ctrl + Shift + down, the up one to find the end. pastes the value then moves across to the other columns. but i can only get this to run on the first section it needs to repeat until the end. the end is defined on row 10000:

```
Sub Sort_The_Fus_To_One_Line_2()
   Application.Goto Reference:="R8C2"
   Range("B8").Select
   Selection.End(xlDown).Select
   Selection.Copy
   Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
   Range("B10:B43").Select
   ActiveSheet.Paste
   Range("E10").Select
   Application.CutCopyMode = False
   Selection.Copy
   Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
   Range("E10:E43").Select
   ActiveSheet.Paste
   Range("H10").Select
   Application.CutCopyMode = False
   Selection.Copy
   Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
   Range("H10:H43").Select
   ActiveSheet.Paste
   Range("B10").Select
   Selection.End(xlDown).Select
End Sub
```

Can someone help!? Thanks!

Comment: You say you ran some VBA code, would you please provide the code you are talking about?

Comment: I'm can't figure what you mean by _To copy it will look for column A to match but look for the top line of the match so there is values in column B._.  I understand you want to copy columns `B`, `E` & `H` down from start row to end row.  The start row is defined as _column D having a value and column B not having a value_. How is the end row defined? Something to do with a match in column `A`?  Could you also edit your question with the code you have - include code tags for formatting please. :)

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook i have updated the questions. please let me know if this make more sense. :)

Comment: @Luuklag Updated the question with the code.

Comment: As you might have noticed Ctrl + Shift + Down actually doesn't get recorded as Ctrl + Shift + Down, you'll need a workaround.

Comment: No, make little sense.  Your explanation says if there's a value in column `D` but your code doesn't look at column `D`. What's it looking at column `A` to match for?  What figure is matching?

Comment: Do you want your code to just fill in the blanks in columns B, E & H?  i.e. Go to the first value in column B and copy that down (along with E & H) until the next value in column B (assuming there's blank cells between the first and second value).

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook yes thats it. but will need to continue once it hits the next one and the code will finish on line 10000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *think* this is something like what you're after:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim rStart As Range, rEnd As Range
    Dim FirstAdd As String
    Dim lLastRow As Long

    lLastRow = 10001

    With Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns(2)
        'Find the first non-blank cell in column B.
        Set rStart = .Find(What:="*", _
                        LookIn:=xlValues, _
                        LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlNext)

        'rStart will be Nothing if the column is empty.
        If Not rStart Is Nothing Then
            FirstAdd = rStart.Address 'Very first found address.

            Do
                'Find the next non-blank cell in column B.
                Set rEnd = .FindNext(rStart)

                If rEnd.Row < rStart.Row And rStart.Row < lLastRow Then
                    'The cell reference is relative to the column in the With command.
                    'making column 1 = sheet column 2.
                    Set rEnd = .Cells(lLastRow, 1)
                End If

                'If the second address isn't the same as the very first address and
                'the second address isn't the row below the start address then copy the value down.
                If rEnd.Address <> FirstAdd And rStart.Offset(1).Address <> rEnd.Address Then

                    'Places the value from the Start row into every cell between one below the
                    'start row to one cell above the end row.
                    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(rStart.Offset(1), rEnd.Offset(-1)) = rStart.Value
                    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(rStart.Offset(1), rEnd.Offset(-1)).Offset(, 3) = rStart.Offset(, 3).Value
                    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(rStart.Offset(1), rEnd.Offset(-1)).Offset(, 6) = rStart.Offset(, 6).Value
                End If

                'Set the new start address as the previous end address.
                Set rStart = rEnd

            Loop While rStart.Row < lLastRow
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Good stuff.  Feel free to tick as the accepted answer. :)